# How to add a .jar in build.xml?

Tags: java, ant, jar, classpath

I have a java web program that implements a .jar and cannot compile without it.  I have uploaded all of the files with appropriate directory names, but I do not know how to get the build.xml to know where to find the .jar.  The jar file is in my src/program directory.  I know I need to use the `<classpath>` tag.  Do I need to put it in my "compile" target inside of the `<javac>` tag?

Comment: Do you just want to add it to the compile classpath or something else as well (such as including the jar contents in your build output)?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="helloworld" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property name="project.src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="project.lib.dir" value="${basedir}/src/program"/>
    <property name="project.classes.dir" value="${basedir}/classes"/>

    <path id="lib.path">
        <fileset dir="${project.lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="${project.src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" destdir="${project.classes.dir}" classpathref="lib.path"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the jar to the classpath attribute or `<classpath>` tag of your [`<javac>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) tag.

Example straight from the ant user guide.

```
<javac srcdir="${src}"
         destdir="${build}"
         classpath="xyz.jar"
         debug="on"
         source="1.4"
/>
```